# Getting an error during initialization of the Google Stack Driver appender

Tags: log4net, google-cloud-stackdriver, log4net-configuration

Have a google stack driver appender in my log4net configuration but during initialization I get an error about not being able to cast as an IAppender. Here's the reference for the [appender](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net/latest/Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net.GoogleStackdriverAppender).

```
<appender name="CloudLogger" type="Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net.GoogleStackdriverAppender,Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
    <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
    <member value="date:date" />
    <member value="level:level" />
    <member value="logger:logger" />
    <member value="message:messageObject" />
    <member value="exception:exception" />
  </layout>
  <projectId value="playground" />
  <logId value="test-api" />
</appender>
```

Error output.

*log4net: Loading Appender [CloudLogger] type: [Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net.GoogleStackdriverAppender,Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net]
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [CloudLogger] of type [Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net.GoogleStackdriverAppender,Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net]. Reported error follows.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net.GoogleStackdriverAppender' to type 'log4net.Appender.IAppender'.
at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [CloudLogger] not found.*

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. Appeared to be a version mismatch between log4net versions in  different projects between the solution.